# jaydebeapi teradata connection

Tags: python, jdbc, teradata, jaydebeapi

I am trying to connect to teradata database using jaydebeapi package.

```
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver',
                          ['jdbc:teradata://ip/TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=utf8', 'username', 'password'],
                          ['/teradata/tdgssconfig.jar',
                           '/terajdbc4.jar'])
```

Error while execution:

```
    TERAJDBC4 ERROR [main] com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection@3d1a70a7 Connection to <ip_address> Wed Oct 07 13:47:29 IST 2015 socket orig=<ip_address> cid=22f79598 sess=0 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF$ConnectThread.run(TDNetworkIOIF.java:1216) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_teradata.py", line 32, in <module>
    teradataconn()
  File "test_teradata.py", line 26, in teradataconn
    '/home/abhishek/git/dblore/code/lib/teradata/terajdbc4.jar'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 359, in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, jars, libs, *driver_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 183, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(*driver_args)
jpype._jexception.SQLExceptionPyRaisable: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 1277] [SQLState 08S01] Login timeout for Connection to <ip_address> Wed Oct 07 13:47:29 IST 2015 socket orig=<ip_address> cid=22f79598 sess=0 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)  at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.io.TDNetworkIOIF$ConnectThread.run(TDNetworkIOIF.java:1216)
```

Comment: "SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out" there is no server with ip, or it doesn't respond in a timely fashion (eg because of a firewall, or other network problems)

Comment: I am able to connect to the database through Java using the same JDBC driver and parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to connect to a Teradata DB, it works with several servers and databases.

```
import jaydebeapi
server=192.168.3.4
database=dbc
user=dbc
password=dbc

# from TD JDBC readme.txt
jclassname='com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver'
# from TD Studio jdbc:<subprotocol>://<server>:<port>/<database>
url='jdbc:teradata://'+server+'/'+database
# driver args contains the arguments passed to java: DriverManager.getConnections(...)
driver_args=[url,user,password]
# my jars are in CLASSPATH environment variable, if not then put the paths to them into a list, e.g.: jars=[r'C:\Program Files\Teradata\TeraJDBC\terajdbc4.jar;C:\Program Files\Teradata\TeraJDBC\tdgssconfig.jar']
jars=None

jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname,driver_args,jars)
```

Comparing with your code I only see ip (replacing your real IP address, I guess) in your url, do you also have added the database name there to the path? If not, the problem might be there.

Answer (score 0):

I have met a similar problem, and I have a sample like below, hope can helpful:

```
[root@myhost transfer]# cat test_conn.py 
import jaydebeapi
from contextlib import closing


jclassname='com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver'
jdbc_driver_loc = '/opt/spark-2.3.1/jars/terajdbc4-16.20.00.06.jar,/opt/spark-2.3.1/jars/tdgssconfig-16.20.00.06.jar'
jdbc_driver_name = 'com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver'
host='my_teradata.address'

url='jdbc:teradata://' + host + '/TMODE=TERA'
login="teradata_user_name"
psw="teradata_passwd"

sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  A_TERADATA_TABLE_NAME where month_key='202009'"


conn = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname=jdbc_driver_name,
                                  url=url, 
                                  driver_args=[login, psw],
                                  jars=jdbc_driver_loc.split(","))

with closing(conn) as conn:
    with closing(conn.cursor()) as cur:
        cur.execute(sql)
        print(cur.fetchall())
   
[root@myhost transfer]# python test_conn.py
[(7734133,)]
[root@myhost transfer]#
```